# How to make part of angular application exportable by API?

Tags: angular, frontend, server-side-rendering, micro-frontend

I'm facing following challenge: i have an Angular 16 application which contains multiple modules. One module contains reports which are received from API and presented on the frontend. I'd like to export part of the application containing report to different apps (probably in different technologies). Exported part does not have to be interactive, it may be just a screenshot of part of the DOM. Do you have any suggestion how can i achieve that?

I considered rendering modules which are interesting for me on server side but i dont know how can i achieve that

Comment: Do you want share part of your app to different app ? I mean like lets say that you have components, modules which you want to be part of more then one app ?

Comment: Yes - one module containing some components